# Eclipse Neon installation fails because of missing JRE/JDK

Tags: java, eclipse

it opens a web browser and a page tells me that I have to install either JRE or JDK version 1.7.0 or higher. I have installed JRE 1.8.0, in fact in command line I can see:

d:>java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

I also setup JAVA_HOME and PATH accordingly but no luck. Is there something else I can try?

Thanks

I found the issue: I installed JRE X86 while Eclispe wanted the X64 version. I have installed it now and the installation process goes on. I didn't install JDK because I want Eclipse for C++ I don't need Java things. Thanks anyway, I hope this will help others!

Comment: Install a JDK not a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

You need the JDK installed to run Eclipse, or even better, to develope java apps at all...

verify that by doing in a terminal:

```
>javac -version
```